# For loop printing values vertical - Python 3.5

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, tweepy

Let me change the question. I'm collecting tweet ids through tweepy and iterating through the ids for say a favorite/retweet of a certain subject. I'm Having trouble grabbing each id that I post in this list, for some reason it's grabbing them vertically? Any help would be appreciated.

```
ids = ['880420289787699200', '880420289787699200', '880420289946959872', '880420289946959872', '880420290144153601', '880420290144153601', '880420290827780097', '880420290827780097', '880420288370016256', '880420288370016256', '880420291268169728', '880420291268169728', '880420294980235265', '880420294980235265', '880420296599248896', '880420296599248896', '880420296687222786', '880420296687222786', '880420299216478209', '880420299216478209', '880420299040149505', '880420299040149505', '880420298834804736', '880420298834804736', '880420298910081026', '880420298910081026']

for e in ids:
    print (e[0])

#Output:
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

when I use:

```
for e in ids:
    print (e)
```

## Output:

880420289787699200
880420289787699200
880420289946959872
880420289946959872
880420290144153601
880420290144153601
880420290827780097
880420290827780097
880420288370016256
880420288370016256
880420291268169728
880420291268169728
880420294980235265
880420294980235265
880420296599248896
880420296599248896
880420296687222786
880420296687222786
880420299216478209
880420299216478209
880420299040149505
880420299040149505
880420298834804736
880420298834804736
880420298910081026
880420298910081026

I want (e) to be the first id (e.g. 880420289787699200). This may be a simple fix, I just have been stuck on it.

Comment: Why are you doing `print (e[0])`? Did you try just printing `print(e)`?

Comment: You're only grabbing the first letter of `e`, so that all that's printing. Just get rid of the `[0]` to print e.

Comment: Yeah, as @idjaw says, you're drilling down when you shouldn't. `e` will be the ID itself, `e[0]` gets the first character of that string instead.

Comment: There is no vertical or horizontal things in a list. In your for loop, `e` is an element of the list: the first, then the second, ... You may just want to go to the next line every time you print. try `print(e+"\n")`

Comment: @BoilingFire Strange thing is that `print` is supposed to add the "\n" by default. I tried the code without the "+\n" just to be sure, and it indeed prints each id on a separate line.

Comment: @bli I know but it was just to be sure that somehow a simple `print` isn't a shortcut for `print(end=" ")`

Answer (score 2):

Without `e[0]` as you already loop through ids, each e then is one id.

For example, at the first iteration `e` equals to `'880415003748257793'`, So when you type `e[0]` you get 8 as this is the first char of the string.

```
for e in ids:
    print (e)
```

Comment: When I type:
    for e in ids:
        print(e)

My output is as follows:

880420289787699200
880420289787699200
880420289946959872
880420289946959872

Comment: Which is what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: no I am looking to grab each id individually print(e) grabs them all at once which is why I was using print(e[0]). I elaborated more in the question above.

Comment: Each iteration `e` holds a different id from the list of ids.

Answer (score 2):

By doing `print (e[0])` you are printing the first letter in each string. If you instead write `print (e)` you will print the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

Each e in ids represents a number, so e[0] represents its first digit.

```
ids = ['880415003748257793', '880415005073702912','880415004809408512','880415007942619136', '880415008470908930','880415010987560960', '880415011105067009', '880415011709083648']

for e in ids:
    print (e[0]) # prints first digit
    print (e) # prints number
```

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need a loop to get the first id**. Just extract it directly from its list:

```
ids = ['880415003748257793', '880415005073702912','880415004809408512','880415007942619136', '880415008470908930','880415010987560960', '880415011105067009', '880415011709083648']

# Note: no space needed after "print" in python 3
# (print is a normal function in python 3)
print(ids[0])
```

In your loop, `e` successively takes the values of the elements in `ids`, so in the first round, you get `"880415003748257793"`, in the second, you get `"880415005073702912"`, etc. And your `e[0]` extracts the first letter of these ids (which all start with '8', hence the output you observe).

Comment: this works, but to iterate through it using a for loop if I want a function to complete an action for each id if I simply use the for loop it does not work. Improved quesiton above.

Comment: I still don't understand what doesn't work. What action do you want to do for each id? In your code, the action you do in the loop is to print the current id. It seems to be working properly (except that print normally inserts a end of line, and in the output you display, strangely, the ids are separated by spaces instead of being each on a separate line.)